# The "Date" in Ubuntu 18.04 Lock Screen is not always center aligned. How to fix?

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen, gdm, css

In Ubuntu 18.04, there appears to be an issue with the alignment of the shown "Date" in the locked screen, i.e. `.screen-shield-clock-date{}` in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`. It sometimes appear center-aligned and sometimes left-aligned w.r.t `.screen-shield-clock{}`. It seems that `.screen-shield-clock-date{}` is a child of

```
.screen-shield-clock {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em; }
```

which already contains the `text-align: center` argument to require center alignment.

I have tried adding `margin: auto; width: 100%;` in both `.screen-shield-clock{}` and `.screen-shield-clock-date{}`, and also adding `text-align: center` in `.screen-shield-clock-date{}` but these approaches don't seem to work?

**Questions:**

1. How can I fix this alignment issue? I want the date to always be center aligned in the screen.
2. May I know which program/file is reading in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`?

Comment: Seems like a bug that you should report

Comment: @Tooniis Where do I report this?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: @Tooniis Thanks. I have reported the issue under [Ubuntu gdm3 package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1840265).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a bug in the Ubuntu gdm3 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4 package. I have reported [it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1840265).

I discovered the trigger for this issue. It occurs when `Tweaks-->Top Bar-->Seconds` is toggled on. For now, the solution to this issue is not to show the "Seconds" in the timing. `Tweaks-->Top Bar-->Seconds` must be toggled off.